# Rounding of float values

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have the `double` value like `12.256852651` and I want to display it as `12.257` as a float number without converting it in to a string type.

How can I do it in C# ?

Comment: Math.Round(value, 3) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "and not as a string format"? You're formatting the number as a string in order to display it, aren't you?

Comment: Perhaps it going over the wire as a number (json, say). It might need to be stored as a number client side in addition to being converted to a string for display in a UI. Just a guess based on similar usage cases here.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'd first convert to `Decimal` and then use `Math.Round` on the result. This conversion is not strictly necessary, but I always feel a bit uneasy if I round to decimal places while using binary floating points.

```
Math.Round((Decimal)f, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

You should also look into the choice of [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx), since by default this uses Banker's round, which is not what you are used to from school.

Comment: Remember, when rounding a binary (as opposed to `System.Decimal`) floating-point type to a number of decimals greater than `0`, that typically the "midpoint" is not exactly representable. For example the "midpoint" `12.2565` (the average of neighbours `12.256` and `12.257`) is not exactly representable as a `double` since its binary expansion is infinite (periodic) (which is very often the case). So there is a good reason to try to convert to `decimal` before the rounding if one wants "midpoints" to actually be hit. With `double` there is often a "hole" where the midpoint should have been.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to display it, it will be a string and that's what you need to use.

If you want to *round* in order to use it later in calculations, use `Math.Round((decimal)myDouble, 3)`.

If you don't intend to use it in calculation but need to *display* it, use `double.ToString("F3")`.